# ssh script doesn't return control to the parent script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to execute a local script on the remote server, by writing it to standard input of an `ssh` command. The script runs fine, but then `ssh` doesn't exit: it just hangs, and control doesn't return to the parent script.

Parent  Shell :

```
for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
    ssh -t -t $HOSTNAME "bash -s" < ~backup_conf.sh 
done
```

Called Script:

```
#!/bin/sh    
AGENT_BASE_PATH=/home/lokesh

if [ -d "$AGENT_BASE_PATH/CI/DE_deployment/conf" ]; then 
        if [ -d "$AGENT_BASE_PATH/CI/temp/conf_bkup" ]; then 
            rm -rf $AGENT_BASE_PATH/CI/temp/conf_bkup
        fi  
        cp -R $AGENT_BASE_PATH/CI/DE_deployment/conf $AGENT_BASE_PATH/CI/temp/conf_bkup
fi
exit
```

I have written 'exit' but the control is not returning back to the parent script.
It hangs at the remote server....   :(

Comment: There's no need for `-s` here -- commands will be read from stdin without it. Likewise, no need for the explicit `exit`.

If you were running anything that left background jobs running (or other output to terminal), this would make great sense as http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/063.

Comment: I'd advise **not** using `-t` here, by the way -- there's no point in having a terminal for strictly noninteractive use. You might be careful of any startup scripts on the remote end kicking off background processes holding the terminal open. Pass `-x` to the shell you're kicking off to make anything happening along those lines more visible.

Comment: Thanks Charles and Anubhava removing -s does the job for me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Culprit is `bash -s` line in your calling code, which is still expecting input to be ended using `ctrl-C`:

Try this instead:

```
for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
    ssh -t -t $HOSTNAME "bash ~backup_conf.sh"
done
```

Answer (score -2):

write your exit - status into a file on the remote host and pick it later from the remote host with ssh/scp/sftp.

Direct via ssh you will not get a exit - status from the other host.

Comment: This is incorrect. ssh does transmit exit status over the channel.

Comment: Plus he is not complaining about the exit status but about the ssh-process not terminating once the remote script has run.